# How to accept and handle incoming calls

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I was able to start up a simple python server from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I was able to use a `curl` command and see that it does respond with a listing of my directory. I was able to see a 200 GET message pop up on my running server, but no other information. However, is there a way of actually seeing the data in the request come in on the server and parsing it? If someone was to post some information to my server (say in JSON format), how can I actually see all this data.. or even an URL?

Are there any examples which actually build on the above code which show how to handle data coming in? A use case would be someone posting information to the server.

Answer (score 1):

When a `GET` request comes in (as is sent to your server by `curl`), `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET` is called behind the scenes. `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` is itself a subclass of [`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler).

You can define your own subclass of `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`:

```
class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET():
        # your code here
        super(MyHandler, self).do_GET()

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyHandler)
```

In place of `# your code here`, you can inspect properties defined by `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` e.g. `self.path` and print them or do whatever you want with them.